# Which Elasticsearch version will work with Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, magento2.4

I am planning to upgrade to 2.4 CE and I was wondering will Magento work on Elasticsearch 7.8 or is it better to go to 7.0?

Anyone tested this yet?

Comment: As per official Magento docs, you must install ESv7.6.x before upgrading to Magento 2.4
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2.4 Requried 7.6 Elasticsearch version, and for configuration process, you should go through with this blog.
https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-configure-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.4.0 supports only Elasticsearch 7.6.x version. It does not support lower versions. https://prnt.sc/u38uj4
You can read more information on Magento devdocs for Magento 2.4.0 release notes on this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html